# How do I construct an TensorFlow Input layer with a variable-length 1-dimensional shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am currently working on a TensorFlow project where I need to handle a variable-shaped input (one-dimensional) because I am dealing with data that accumulates over time. At the beginning of the artificial intelligence system's life, there is no information regarding this data, but at each step, the sensor reads and adds this information. Therefore, I need to define an input that can accommodate an indefinite number of data points.

I have already tried to define None as input shape but I got the following error:

`ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to a Dense layer should be defined. Found None. Full input shape received: (None, None)`

Thank you in advance for your help!